Bootstrap class mx-auto does not center an element
So I've been working on a website that utilizes the Bootstrap 5 navbar. I basically have 3 navbar-navs, one with me-auto, one with mx-auto and one with ms-auto. The me-auto and ms-auto navbar-navs (which I want to use as kind of a side space for icons and small stuff) work fine, but the one with mx-auto (which is the main navbar) doesn't. The "^" indicates the complete center of the screen and I want the navbar-brand to be exactly positioned over that. Instead, it is positioned more off to the right.
HTML Code:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-md-none" href="#">
                <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto d-none d-md-flex">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-icon" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-spotify"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-icon" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path fill="white" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1" d="M36,5H14c-4.971,0-9,4.029-9,9v22c0,4.971,4.029,9,9,9h22c4.971,0,9-4.029,9-9V14C45,9.029,40.971,5,36,5z M38.19,21.254 c0.65-0.279,1.42-0.317,2.07-0.121c0.27,0.084,0.51,0.196,0.74,0.335v1.23c-0.72-0.494-1.55-0.634-2.19-0.289   c-0.68,0.373-1.08,1.155-1.06,1.975c-0.01,0.904,0.29,1.742,0.92,2.133c0.56,0.382,1.44,0.382,2.33,0.242v1.025 c-0.35,0.112-0.72,0.177-1.1,0.214c-0.63,0.047-1.33-0.047-1.95-0.382c-0.63-0.326-1.09-0.894-1.35-1.463   c-0.25-0.587-0.34-1.183-0.35-1.752C36.22,23.191,36.87,21.831,38.19,21.254z M34,18.01c0.552,0,1,0.448,1,1s-0.448,1-1,1   s-1-0.448-1-1S33.448,18.01,34,18.01z M34.75,21.01v7h-1.5v-7H34.75z M27,26.175c0.64,0.261,1.42,0.532,2.03,0.59   c0.61,0.068,1.28-0.01,1.67-0.223c0.19-0.116,0.23-0.278,0.23-0.458s-0.036-0.282-0.123-0.417c-0.159-0.246-0.597-0.432-1.287-0.597 c-0.34-0.097-0.71-0.194-1.12-0.416c-0.41-0.184-1.243-0.852-1.081-1.991c0.087-0.609,0.718-1.205,1.601-1.483  c1.029-0.325,2.15-0.164,3.08,0.281V22.7c-0.83-0.426-1.82-0.641-2.66-0.361c-0.25,0.077-0.58,0.251-0.58,0.564 c0,0.751,0.87,0.893,1.2,1c0.34,0.106,0.71,0.203,1.11,0.406c0.4,0.194,1.202,0.678,1.202,1.783c0,1.058-0.522,1.447-0.952,1.621    c-0.89,0.387-1.68,0.319-2.45,0.213c-0.65-0.116-1.28-0.31-1.87-0.677C27,27.249,27,26.175,27,26.175z M20.25,21.012l1.5-0.002  l0.003,2.42c0.014,0.79,0.012,1.651,0.003,2.383c-0.035,0.391,0.402,0.847,0.976,0.917c0.306,0.034,0.534,0.009,0.886-0.14  c0.208-0.082,0.42-0.152,0.632-0.225V21.01l1.5,0.001v6.818h-1.5v-0.236c-0.041,0.022-0.08,0.046-0.12,0.067    c-0.381,0.228-0.992,0.386-1.514,0.343c-0.542-0.035-1.088-0.225-1.533-0.586c-0.442-0.356-0.776-0.915-0.819-1.529 c-0.027-0.88-0.02-1.634-0.011-2.457L20.25,21.012z M9.25,21.01h1.5v0.688c0.37-0.134,0.737-0.274,1.109-0.401  c0.535-0.19,1.206-0.152,1.733,0.141c0.218,0.117,0.409,0.282,0.577,0.469c0.562-0.208,1.123-0.417,1.689-0.611 c0.535-0.19,1.206-0.152,1.733,0.141c0.532,0.286,0.946,0.809,1.093,1.418c0.039,0.152,0.056,0.306,0.065,0.461l0.004,0.317 l0.006,0.625l-0.006,1.25l-0.003,2.5h-1.5l-0.006-4.844c-0.042-0.425-0.519-0.797-1.019-0.661c-0.51,0.135-1.024,0.255-1.537,0.379  c0.034,0.143,0.052,0.287,0.061,0.433l0.004,0.317l0.006,0.625l-0.006,1.25l-0.003,2.5h-1.5l-0.006-4.844   c-0.042-0.426-0.519-0.797-1.019-0.661c-0.489,0.13-0.983,0.245-1.475,0.364v5.14h-1.5C9.25,28.006,9.25,21.01,9.25,21.01z M38.768,33.932c-2.214,1.57-4.688,2.605-7.285,3.277c-2.595,0.663-5.297,0.914-7.986,0.729c-2.688-0.18-5.313-0.836-7.787-1.794  c-2.466-0.99-4.797-2.263-6.857-3.931c-0.107-0.087-0.124-0.245-0.037-0.352c0.077-0.095,0.209-0.119,0.313-0.063l0.014,0.008   c2.249,1.217,4.653,2.149,7.067,2.889c2.433,0.692,4.909,1.187,7.4,1.288c2.485,0.087,4.997-0.107,7.449-0.617  c2.442-0.504,4.905-1.236,7.17-2.279l0.039-0.018c0.251-0.115,0.547-0.006,0.663,0.245C39.035,33.537,38.961,33.796,38.768,33.932z M39.882,36.892c-0.278,0.21-0.556,0.14-0.417-0.21c0.417-1.12,1.32-3.501,0.903-4.061c-0.486-0.63-2.987-0.28-4.098-0.14 c-0.347,0-0.347-0.28-0.069-0.49c0.972-0.7,2.292-0.98,3.404-0.98c1.111,0,2.084,0.21,2.292,0.56   C42.243,31.99,41.757,35.281,39.882,36.892z"></path></svg></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-icon" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="white" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 16.5h2v.5H3zm5 0h2.5v.5H8zm8 .5h-2.5v-.5H16zm5.5 0H19v-.5h2.5zm0-4H19v.5h2.5zm0-3.5H19v.5h2.5zm0-3.5H19v.5h2.5zM16 13h-2.5v.5H16zm-8 .5h2.5V13H8zm0-4h2.5v.5H8z"></path></svg></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-icon" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><svg class="outline-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path fill="white" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M 9 12 C 8.7615 12 8.5237969 12.091437 8.3417969 12.273438 L 1.2734375 19.341797 C 0.9094375 19.705797 0.9094375 20.294203 1.2734375 20.658203 L 8.3417969 27.726562 C 8.7057969 28.090563 9.2942031 28.090563 9.6582031 27.726562 L 16.726562 20.658203 C 16.908563 20.476203 17 20.2385 17 20 C 17 19.7615 16.908563 19.523797 16.726562 19.341797 L 9.6582031 12.273438 C 9.4762031 12.091437 9.2385 12 9 12 z M 17 20 C 17 20.2385 17.091438 20.476203 17.273438 20.658203 L 24.341797 27.726562 C 24.523797 27.908563 24.7615 28 25 28 C 25.2385 28 25.476203 27.908563 25.658203 27.726562 L 32.726562 20.658203 C 32.908563 20.476203 33 20.2385 33 20 C 33 19.7615 32.908563 19.523797 32.726562 19.341797 L 25.658203 12.273438 C 25.294203 11.909437 24.705797 11.909437 24.341797 12.273438 L 17.273438 19.341797 C 17.091437 19.523797 17 19.7615 17 20 z M 33 20 C 33 20.2385 33.091437 20.476203 33.273438 20.658203 L 40.341797 27.726562 C 40.705797 28.090563 41.294203 28.090563 41.658203 27.726562 L 48.726562 20.658203 C 49.090563 20.294203 49.090563 19.705797 48.726562 19.341797 L 41.658203 12.273438 C 41.294203 11.909437 40.705797 11.909437 40.341797 12.273438 L 33.273438 19.341797 C 33.091437 19.523797 33 19.7615 33 20 z M 25 28 C 24.7615 28 24.523797 28.091437 24.341797 28.273438 L 17.273438 35.341797 C 16.909437 35.705797 16.909437 36.294203 17.273438 36.658203 L 24.341797 43.726562 C 24.705797 44.090562 25.294203 44.090562 25.658203 43.726562 L 32.726562 36.658203 C 33.090563 36.294203 33.090563 35.705797 32.726562 35.341797 L 25.658203 28.273438 C 25.476203 28.091437 25.2385 28 25 28 z"></path></svg></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-icon" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2.3vw" height="2.3vh" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path fill="white" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1" d="M37,4H13c-4.962,0-9,4.037-9,9v24c0,4.963,4.038,9,9,9h24c4.962,0,9-4.037,9-9V13C46,8.037,41.962,4,37,4z M35,27v4v0.021  h-0.002C34.986,33.768,32.749,36,30,36h-0.5c-0.987,0-1.933-0.42-2.596-1.152c-0.662-0.731-0.985-1.718-0.887-2.705 C26.195,30.38,27.787,29,29.643,29H31c1.103,0,2-0.897,2-2v-9.795l-12,2.25V30v4c0,2.757-2.243,5-5,5h-0.5  c-0.987,0-1.933-0.42-2.596-1.152c-0.662-0.731-0.985-1.718-0.887-2.705C12.195,33.38,13.787,32,15.643,32H17c1.103,0,2-0.897,2-2   V15.353c0-0.963,0.687-1.79,1.633-1.966l12.591-2.36c0.439-0.083,0.891,0.033,1.234,0.319C34.803,11.632,35,12.053,35,12.5V27z"></path></svg></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/band/">Band</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pictures</a>
                    </li>
                    <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="/">
                        <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                    </a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lorem</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto d-none d-md-flex">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-icon" href="/contact"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<p class="text-center text-white">^</p>

CSS Code:
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-brand img {
        width: 100px !important;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-right: 0;
        padding: 0 1em;
    }
}
.navbar-brand img {
    width: 70px;
}
.navbar-nav {
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: .5em 1em;
}
.nav-icon {
    width: 1vw;
}

I tried to apply me-auto, mx-auto and ms-auto and expected the navbar-nav with mx-auto to be completely centered. Instead, it's moved to the right.
Edit: I've noticed that removing mx-auto from the middle navbar-nav does absolutely nothing, so it seems not important.

mx-auto seems to have a default margin on the left. If we eliminate it then the content should be centered.
        ul.mx-auto {
            margin-left: 0 !important;
        }

Don't have the full context on the project though so I might be wrong.

@ElCrossaint322 Funny enough, when I tried that code, it just randomly got put to the left by the same amount of pixels as before. So it basically switched sides. Lol. Also, what do you mean by full context? Should I upload the entire HTML code?
